# Does Caffe Scale up to multiple CPU Cores?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I wish to run Caffe on a 32 core machine.

1. Does caffe scale up to available number of cores to utilize them the best?
2. Although there are 32 cores, can I make caffe use only a selected number of cores?

Answer (score 5):

Generally **caffe** doesn't support multiple CPUs/cores in its source code, but it uses **BLAS** routines.

Thus answers to your questions are the following:

1. Yes, but only through **BLAS** configuration, i. e. your **BLAS** version should be compiled with multithreading support (see related discussions: [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1492) or [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/439) - at the second link you can also find some modifications for **caffe** itself).
2. Also through **BLAS** (if it was compiled with **openmp** support, you can define `OMP_NUM_THREADS` to desired value).

Answer (score 0):

caffe does not, but you can you Intel caffe which is optimized for CPU and supports multi node
https://github.com/intel/caffe/wiki/Multinode-guide